# Casting warnings in methods with variable arguments

Tags: c++, c, objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary

Sorry if the question isn't correct, I'm very new in Objective-C.
I understand why this code throw the Warning: *"warning: passing argument 1 of 'initWithObjectsAndKeys:' makes pointer from integer without"*

```
NSDictionary *dictNames =
[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
     3, @"",
     4, @"",
     5, @"",nil];
```

Keys and Values of a NSDictionary must be NSObject and not fundamental types, like the integers 3, 4 and 5. (Correct me if necessary).
But I don't understand why this warning dissapears with the only "correct typing" of the first Key.

```
NSDictionary *dictNames =
    [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
     [NSNumber numberWithInteger:3], @"",
     4, @"",
     5, @"",nil];
```

It's because NSDictionary assumes the type of the other Keys? Is correct this manner of initialization?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The prototype of the method you mentioned is

```
-(id)initWithObjectsAndKeys:(id)firstObject, ...;
```

Thus the first parameter must be an ObjC object. But the rest are passed by varargs. In C, any primitives can be passed as vararg arguments (think `printf`). Hence the compiler won't issue any warnings.

While the compiler is incapable of chekcing the types of the vararg arguments, it doesn't mean passing non-`id` into the method is valid.

Comment: I see... in fact when I have to get an Object by Key I have to do it with an objectForKey:(id)aKey then the Objects and then Keys must be (id).

Thanks for the answer :-)

Comment: Is it a hard requirement for the 1st arg to be a Obj C object? If not, what should be the syntax of the declaration?

Comment: @Saptarshi: No, e.g. `-(int)foo:(int)firstInt, ...`